# Novel from 70's/80's. Book collector buys a lot of books, finds a rare one. Starts to study book then people start to die

Tags: story-identification, novel

An avid book collector chances upon an auction and buys a lot of assorted books. I think the auction was held in a chateau. The lot of books turns up and, when he goes through them, he finds something rare and special. Upon studying this book things start to happen. The book was, I suppose, a gateway to a higher level of being, something left by those that had gone before as an aid or primer to guide and help the next ones who come along.

As the book is read and studied, things start to happen: people start to die, torn apart, ripped to pieces. People are discovered like this even within rooms locked from the inside. If I remember correctly, it has to do with the darker side of the mind, monsters from the "Id" to quote from [that grand old film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049223/quotes). The journey to this higher level of being involves leaving behind this dark side. It becomes a residue and those that had gone before had left such a residue; the awakening of this evolution stirs it all up.

Final part of the book talks about how the Earth is silent, no sign of man anywhere, then it talks about an ape finding the book and it ends.

Comment: `...then it talks about an ape finding the book... ` Oh man! I want to read that!!

Comment: So do I again :), had a copy for years but somehow it went missing.

Answer (score 1):

The last part definitely sounds like the ending of *Lost Legacy*, the second of the four novellas in Robert A. Heinlein's **Assignment in Eternity**. An 'ape with a brain too big for his soul' (not an exact quote; I don't have it in front of me) climbs a mountain and receives the dream of the Fall of Atlantis that the main characters receive earlier in the story.

However, none of the rest matches *Lost Legacy*, not even vaguely. Could you be conflating two different stories?

Comment: I know the story you are talking about,but I am afraid that is not it ,it is one novel pretty sure on that and the ape does nothing other than find the book and then it end's. Thank you though